# PowerAutomate, SQL trigger : When an item is modified (V2)

Tags: sql-server, power-automate

I'm using flows since a few months, and now i'm trying to create one for emailing the clients when the "PHONE_DATE" field is updated. And i can't juste use trigger "WHEN an item is modified" in all the table because some other actions are done and don't need to send a mail after.

basicaly the flow is just :

1. Trigger sql : when one specified field is modified
2. SQL query : using the triggeroutput(CLI_ID) in a query for the email in another table
3. Control flow : if not null > send mail, using the mail field with the dynamic one

But my problem is i'm unable to make the $select or $filter working

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/sql/#when-an-item-is-modified-(v2)][1]

the docs isn't helping.

I did test like :

- SELECT PHONE_DATE FROM TABLE
- SELECT PHONE_DATE
- PHONE_DATE
- [PHONE_DATE]
- [dbo].[PHONE_DATE]
- UPDATE TABLE set column

And each time the error message isn't usefull :"isn't working, query not as exepted"

So what is the exepted scheme for this field ?

```
    $select         string  

Specific fields to retrieve from entries (default = all).
```